# Using a calculated value in two places in a postgresql query

Tags: postgresql

I want to calculate the distance between two lat-longs, and display that value. 
I also want to use that value (rounded to the nearest KM)

NOTE: Contrived example

Here's what I have

```
SELECT  
ST_Distance(
   ST_GeogFromText(
     'SRID=4326;POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')'
   ),
   ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(1 1)')
 ) AS distance, id from locations limit 10
```

Now this works perfectly well..  I get distance in meters

But I want to get the distance in both meters and km  (for this question that is simple enough)

Here's what I thought would work

```
SELECT  
ST_Distance(
   ST_GeogFromText(
     'SRID=4326;POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')'
   ),
   ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(1 1)')
 ) AS distance, distance/1000 as distance_in_km, id from locations limit 10
```

This returns an error..
**column "distance" does not exist**
It has the arrow pointing at the second "distance" in the query.

What I'd really like to avoid is having the calculation in both the full value and the rounded to KM

Please note: This is not the actual query, but one that was contrived to present the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this out :-

```
SELECT distance, distance/1000 as distance_in_km from 
(
    SELECT  
        ST_Distance(
            ST_GeogFromText(
            'SRID=4326;POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')'
        ),
        ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(1 1)')
    ) AS distance, id from locations limit 10
) t;
```

Comment: Now I have to figure out how to change the from clause of an active record call.